# Gateway receives Join Request from end device, but it doesn't accept

Tags: lorawan

I'm quite new to IoT in general.

I have a Dragino LPS8v2 gateway, and I would like to create a private LoRaWAN network for my end device (TTGO T-Beam).

**What I did :**

- configure GW's LoRa parameters (frequency plan)
- configure built-in LoRaWAN server (semtech UDP). As mentioned in the Dragino documentation, I selected as primary LoRaWAN server `The Things Network V3`, and as second server `Local Host/Built-in Server`

[image: Gateway's LoRaWAN setup]

- Register gateway in The Things Stack Open Source by clicking the link in the GW's configuration page (System -> Built-in Server)

[image: Link to The Things Stack Open Source]

**What I expect :**

I expect my end device to connect to the Dragino gateway, and therefore use the built-in LoRaWAN server.

**What is happening :**

- GW seems ok (logs show nothing special)
- end device sends Join Request to gateway, but connects to another near gateway (which is connected to TTN).

For context, the Dragino GW is next to the end device (<1 meter, because I'm trying to set it up and debugging). The other GW is 5-10 meters away.

Also, when checking the Dragino's traffic, the `DEVEUI` seen is the one of my end device, used for an application on The Things Network.

I have a few questions:

1. Why is the end device not connecting to the Dragino GW ? Is it because it is too near? Or because the other GW responded faster?
2. Is it correct to choose as primary LoRaWAN server the `The Things Network V3`, even though I want to use the built-in LoRaWAN server? And if so, why?
3. When using a built-in LoRaWAN server, the GW shouldn't be connected to The Things Network, is that right?
4. Should I add an application in The Things Stack, as well as an end device? I already created an app and registered the end device on The Things Network...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is facing the same problem, here's what I did to make it work:

- create an application on The Things Stack Open Source (available by clicking on the link of the built-in LoraWAN server)
- add an end device
- change the Dragino GW's primary LoRaWAN server to `Local Host/Built-in Server` and disable the secondary one

And it worked. The reason why there was no Join Accept is because the end device had the wrong keys (AppKey, DEVEUI, etc), and the primary LoRaWAN server was not correctly configured.

Check this post : [#6034 LoRaWAN device not receiving Join Accept](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/6034/19652)

Hope this can help!